# how voltage drop between collector and emitter can be increased?

Tags: transistors

I can't understand how  the voltage drop from the collector and the emitter (Vce) can increase.Why it isn't standard?

Comment: The voltage drop between the collector and emitter of a BJT depends on many factors.  Why would it be constant or "standard"?  Maybe you are talking about VCEsat?  In that case it's roughly constant, but still depends on things like temperature and collector current etc.

Comment: If the voltage drop between collector and emitter didn't change, we couldn't use transistors to build amplifiers or logic circuits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vce changes in the same way as any current source would change with varying load.

A bipolar transistor is in essence a current amplifier in linear mode. so the output more or less behaves as a current source.

Consider a current source arccos 1 LED, then the same across 5 LED's. Current is the same, voltage is different. The same goes (more or less) for Vce

Answer (score 2):

When a transistor is operating in active region it behaves like a current controlled current source. A current source provides a constant current regardless of the voltage across it (here the collector-emitter junction).

[image]

The above picture shows the I-V characteristic of a typical NPN bipolar transistor. The flat curve shows the active region (actually it's not that flat due to the Early effect). Since it's current controlled you can change the (collector) current by changing the base current. The collector-emitter voltage is then not under your control but the circuit itself.

Comment: How is possible that with the same current i have more than one Vce?